# linear_model.py:1283: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt return rho, np.sqrt(sigmasq)

Tags: python-3.6, linear-regression, statsmodels

i have encountered a big problem when I do exercise of time series analysis with plot_ACF and plot_PACF.

when I run my code, it always gives me warning like this:

> linear_model.py:1283: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in
>   sqrt
>
> return rho, np.sqrt(sigmasq)

and I tried to find solution on Google, but found nothing helpful.
Appreciation if someone could help me fix this warning. 
many many thx!

> my coding environment: python 3.6.6 win64
>
> statsmodels lib used in my laptop:
>   statsmodels-0.9.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64

and my source code is listed below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots import plot_acf,plot_pacf

dta=[10930,10318,10595,10972,7706,6756,9092,10551,9722,10913,11151,8186,6422,
6337,11649,11652,10310,12043,7937,6476,9662,9570,9981,9331,9449,6773,6304,9355,
10477,10148,10395,11261,8713,7299,10424,10795,11069,11602,11427,9095,7707,10767,
12136,12812,12006,12528,10329,7818,11719,11683,12603,11495,13670,11337,10232,
13261,13230,15535,16837,19598,14823,11622,19391,18177,19994,14723,15694,13248,
9543,12872,13101,15053,12619,13749,10228,9725,14729,12518,14564,15085,14722,
11999,9390,13481,14795,15845,15271,14686,11054,10395]
dta_list = np.arange(2001,2091)
data=pd.DataFrame(dta,index=dta_list)
data.plot()
plt.show()

D_data=data.diff(1).dropna()
D_data.plot()
plt.show()

plot_acf(D_data).show()
plot_pacf(D_data).show()
```

Comment: i think i find the solution, if i code like plot_pacf(D_data,method='ymw').show(),everything is fine

Comment: what does `method='ymw'` change? To me, it returns: _method not available_ using this command `plot_pacf(y, lags=lags,method='ymw', ax=pacf_ax, alpha=0.5)`

Comment: @SPS ymw is yule walker without bias correction and default method is yule walker with bias correction in the denominator for acovf. If ymw doesn't work, try ywmle to get yule walker without bias correction